# Trying to find multiple values from one column and group by another column - can't seem to figure it out

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a search table which contails all possible values/keywords for a company.

table:

```
id, company_id, value
1   2           grocery store
2   3           mall something
3   2           grocery
4   2           mall
```

*Where company_id is a foreign key to a company table.

I'm trying to find company id with specific partial values, for example in above table i want the companies with values like '%grocery%' and '%mall%' both, In this case company 2 should be returned but company with id 3 should not be. The closes query to this i got is:

```
select company_id from search where (value LIKE 'grocery' OR value LIKE 'mall') group by company_id having count(distinct value) = 2;
```

This *almost* works for me, except I need to use like '%grocery%' (w/ %) to find partial matches too, but the query gives me no results if i use % operator. I believe it's because you can't group by partial matches?

I would greatly appreciate any pointers or tips on how to solve this.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: having count(distinct value) = 2 , what does this do?

Comment: Having a hard time understanding the question, let's consider your example. Do you want to find companies with values containing "grocery" or "mall" partially or exactly? For example a company having values "grocery" and "grocery shopping" should be returned ? Or there has to be a record which has the value "mall" in it too ?

Comment: yes, I'm needing to find partial matches ... so '%grocery%' would return 'grocery store'. Also the company must have both terms (ie, 'grocery' and 'mall') in either one OR multiple columns - in other words, I only want to find companies that are tagged with 'grocery' AND 'mall' however those terms could either be in one or multiple fields. Sorry - if I'm not making sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe it's because you can't group by partial matches?

You are not “grouping” by the `value` column, but by `company_id` instead, so this should not matter.

> ```
> having count(distinct value) = 2
> ```

I think the DISTINCT here is your problem – here partial matches could be problematic.

Try

```
having count(company_id) = 2
```

instead (or maybe even `>= 2` if there might be more results and you still want to catch those company ids) – every row in your search table that contains a match will be selected, so counting how often each company id occurs should do the trick.

---

Edit:

OK, so the problem is if a company has two hits for `mall`, f.e. `mall` and `shopping mall`, but none for `grocery`, you don’t want to find it, but only if `mall` *and* `grocery` are found at least once.

Well, then let’s try this approach:

```
SELECT
  company_id
FROM SEARCH
GROUP BY company_id
HAVING SUM(value LIKE '%grocery%') AND SUM(value LIKE '%mall%')
```

We are summing up how many times `%grocery%` is found, and how many time `%mall%` is found. This can result in either zero or more for each keyword – and with the HAVING clause we demand that both of those have a summed up value of at least 1 (zero counts as false, every other number as true).

See it live here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9130e/7

Does this work better for you?

(Be advised though, that this query might not be very fast on large data sets. An index will not help much since you are looking for partial matches, and HAVING is evaluated only after all rows have been fetched … so that might make it quite slow, involve use of temporary tables etc.)

Comment: Thanks, this makes more sense to me, but doesn't return any results (using either =2 or >=2)

Comment: Here is a modified fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d51bd/1 - you can see that it returns the company "NO" even though that company doesn't have both 'grocery' and 'mall'. (BTW, sqlfiddle is really awesome, can't believe i've never used it before) -- thanks!

Comment: Yes, but that company has `mall` two times – which should not happen in your DB design, but OK `mall` and `shopping mall` might happen. See edit to my answer for another approach.

Comment: Funny, 'mall' and 'shopping mall' is one of the exact reasons I need the partial match. Yes, your edit works! That's great! I'll have to read up on 'SUM' as I've never seen it used in a case like this ... very cool.

Comment: That makes two us, i like it that you can use conditional statements in aggregation functions like this in MYSQL, you can't use it that way in Oracle. Having an Oracle background here. @CBroe

Comment: Yeah, MySQL handles data types kinda lazy (resp. does some “magic” automatic conversion when necessary), so this works. But I think in other, stricter SQL “dialects” you could do it with an IF or CASE statement that explicitly returns 1 for a match or 0 for no match, and then sum those values up.

Comment: I can't find an exact answer, but I'm taking a wild guess in this case that `SUM(value like '%mall%')` etc .. must not be empty/0, or must be 1+ or some value. (@CBroe, I think you just answered this with your last comment - which I missed)

Answer (score 1):

Well this is what you want

```
SELECT * FROM  (

SELECT DISTINCT company_id , value FROM (

SELECT company_id,
  CASE WHEN value LIKE '%grocery%' THEN 'grocery' WHEN value LIKE '%mall%' THEN 'mall'       END AS value FROM SEARCH
    WHERE (value LIKE '%grocery%' OR value LIKE '%mall%')
  ) a
  ) b
GROUP BY b.company_id HAVING count(*) = 2
```

The problem in your query is *count(distinct value)* will count "grocery" and "grocery something" as different records, so your count will probably be more than 2.

Also even if there is no "mall" records for a company but 2 records containing "grocery" partially would be in the result.Even if there is no record containing "mall" in it

Comment: This just blew my mind ... it works as expected! I'm guessing the THEN 'grocery' and THEN 'mall' are what allow it to be grouped? Thank you kindly!

Comment: No, case when statement is a conditional statement changing the resulting value. So if you execute the inner query you will get "grocery" for any record that contains grocery. Then you can filter then result accordingly since all values containing grocery will become exactly "grocery".

The problem in your query is count(distinct value) will count "grocery" and "grocery something" as different records, so your count will probably be more than 2

Also even if there is no mall records for the company a company with 2 records containing "grocery" partially would be in the result.Not what you want

Comment: This is brilliant ... makes perfect sense! I can't thank you enough.